# Crash & Overheating with Nokia Lumia 920

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I just had the following problem with my otherwise reliable Lumia 920.

Context:

- Happened on Nokia Lumia 920 with up-to-date SW
- Was in the main screen
- No background applications were running
- Tapped standard camera app to launch it
- Expected the camera app to run

Problem:

- Screen **went completely black**
- Camera lens was not blocked (it may have been when the app was launched)
- No change occurred after ~1 minute
- Phone **did not respond** to touch screen gestures
- Ditto for physical buttons (long/short presses)
- Ditto for various combinations
- Phone **did not show up** as a device when connected to a laptop using USB cable
- Neither pleading nor yelling made any difference
- Basically the phone appeared to have suffered the SPDS (*sudden-phone-death syndrome*)
- After ~2 hours noticed the phone **was very hot** in the middle area on both sides
- This could be imaginary but it seemed a little "puffed up" and made unusual sounds when squeezed
- The above could be simply due to the fact that the phone was hot (and therefore expanded)
- Removed SIM card (in case the battery was cooking and was about to blow up)
- After ~2 more hours the phone was cold
- When USB cable was plugged in, the phone woke up and indicated than the battery **was discharged**
- I then unplugged the USB cable, put back the SIM card, and charged the phone
- The phone **works fine** ever since

Speculation:

- Seems like SW (OS or cam app) crashed causing the phone to become unresponsive
- And even though it crashed, it (luckily) was doing something intense
- This caused it to run hot and drain the battery rather quickly
- And eventually leading to (much needed) restart due to loss of power

Has anyone experienced the same behavior?  What are possible causes?  How to prevent this from re-occurring?

Comment: Did you use the default app, or another camera app? And how up-to-date? Dev-preview?

Comment: @Andreas: I used the standard built-in cam app.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you really can try is doing a hard reset if this keeps happening. If that doesn't work you might need to contact the Nokia service.

When you notice your phone crashed you should always be able to do a soft reset (keep holding volume down and power button until your phone restarts). This should stop your phone from overheating as well.